# Why does this work? (Change of basis matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: solution]

I’m taking a linear algebra class and we covered how to find the matrix representation of the same linear operator but according to a new basis of the vector space. As example, my professor calculated a change of basis matrix in a manner similar to finding the inverse of a matrix.

My question is: why does this method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of basis matrix $P$ from the standard basis to basis $\mathcal B=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}\:$ is the matrix with columns the coordinates of the vectors of $\mathcal B$. Similarly, the change of basis matrix $P'$ from the standard basis to basis $\mathcal B'=\{e'_1,e'_2,e'_3\}\:$ is the matrix with columns the coordinates of the vectors of $\mathcal B'$.

Now, the coordinates $X$ of a vector in the standard basis are related to its coordinates $Y$ and $Y'$ in bases $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B'$ respectively via the formulæ:
$$X=PY,\quad X=P'Y',\quad\text{ so that }\enspace Y=P^{-1}P'Y'.$$
Therefore, the change of basis matrix from basis $\mathcal B$ to $\mathcal B'$ is the matrix $ P^{-1}P'$.

Now what does the procedure described in your question do? It left multiplies the left-and side of the augmented matrix $\bigl[P\mid P'\bigr]$, i.e.  the matrix $P$ by elementary operations matrices until we obtain the unit $3{\times}3$ matrix. All in all, we have multiplied $P$ by $P^{-1}$.

What happened to  the right-hand side $P'$? We applied the same operations as on the left-hand side, that is we multiplied by $P^{-1}$, obtaining the matrix $P^{-1}P'$ — the change of basis matrix  we were seeking for.

Answer (score 1):

It just works out that what you get is the product $\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\2&3&7\\1&3&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}3&5&1\\1&2&1\\4&1&-6\end{pmatrix}$.

The two matrices, the first of which we take the inverse, are the transition matrices between the given bases and the standard basis.  The trick to seeing that is to note that, relative to itself, the elements of a basis appear as the standard basis elements $e_k$.  And when you apply a matrix to $e_k$, you get the $k$th column.

It's relatively easy to see that row-reducing until we get the identity inverts the first matrix.

So, the trick is to use the standard basis as a sort of common point of reference.  The product above represents going from the second basis, to the standard, and then from the standard to the new basis.

Actually it looks like what he's got is $M^{-1}$.